# Laravel sessions and error log files are enormous

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I noticed something recently that has me a little concerned and at a loss for an explanation. Last week I spun up an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 to start working on a new Laravel app.

Today, I noticed it was taking an unusually long time to sync. I noticed that my sessions folder was close to 1 gig and my log file was over 300 Mb. The log file was full of Token Mismatch Exceptions. Does anybody have any ideas on why this is happening?

I should add that everything is working normally. I just checked my apache access log file and came up with a possible explanation.

```
80.82.65.206 - - [27/Sep/2015:10:33:25 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 500 14213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;  http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
80.82.65.206 - - [27/Sep/2015:10:33:26 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 500 14213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;  http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
80.82.65.206 - - [27/Sep/2015:10:33:27 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 500 14213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;  http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I have about 10k lines of this in my access log. What the hell is going on?

Comment: Maybe that was a DoS or a DDoS. Try Apache access log for more info

Comment: Check my edit. Googlebot?? IP originates in the Netherlands

Comment: Looks like someone masking as a bot and trying to exploit `xmlrpc.php`, which is a WordPress thing: https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/new-brute-force-attacks-exploiting-xmlrpc-in-wordpress.html

Comment: xmlrpc.php exploit seems to be a pretty common brute force attack used against wordpess sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common scan that is used against WordPress sites. See the following:

https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/new-brute-force-attacks-exploiting-xmlrpc-in-wordpress.html

If you notice in your Apache log file, there is no referrer. So using a simple rewrite rule, you can block these requests by putting this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^xmlrcp\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

Alternatively, you can block all `POST` requests to **any** file that don't have a referrer by using this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

Since Laravel won't take `POST` requests unless you setup a [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) or specify that a route should handle `POST` requests, you can ignore these, but I would at least use the first example.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. You know this all started for me this past weekend and I noticed AWS had a reported outage this weekend also which effected most of their services. They are attributing it to a "failure of an internal sub-service that manages table and partition information." Do you think maybe that is a cover story for something they would rather not admit? I mean it brought down Netflix for a few hours.

Comment: I don't think it's a cover story. It's not smart and transparency is important. Their DynamoDB went down is all. It happens.