# Prevent xmlrpc.php from using in nginx and also use Windows Live Writer

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, xml-rpc

My blog is running in wordpress on nginx.
I found a lot of DDOS attack and nginx log is as follows.

```
 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd - - [19/Oct/2015:16:11:50 +0900] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;  http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"
```

I added conf file as follows.

```
location = /xmlrpc.php {
    allow (my global ip);
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    error_log off;
}
```

It seems to work fine to prevent DDOS attack.
But I found that I encounter an error when I use Windows Live Writer. The error dialog is like this.

```
http://(my blog)/xmlrpc.php
405 Not Allowed
```

Seems to be that "allow (my global ip)" and "deny all" are working because Windows Live Writer error message is not 403 but 405. But I cannot find any solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop people abusing XML-RPC file, You may add the following filter into your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', function( $methods ) {
         unset( $methods['pingback.ping'] );
            return $methods;
      } );
```

Source:
https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/03/more-than-162000-WordPress-sites-used-for-distributed-denial-of-service-attack.html

Comment: I think this solution seems working but stil I have a following logs.

80.82.65.206 - - [20/Oct/2015:18:40:51 +0900] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;  http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"

I found this and seems to be same issue. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833194/laravel-sessions-and-error-log-files-are-enormous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833194/laravel-sessions-and-error-log-files-are-enormous).

But now server is nginx and once I add conf file to deny, I cannot use Windows Live Write anymore.....